# Youtube API v3 Javascript sample code not functioning

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I tried to copy the sample youtube api search keyword code for javascript as per the website: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

I went to the developer console, generated a client ID using both localhost as well as my IP address and it always shows me the search bar with the search button disabled. As per someone else's suggestion, I even tried to put all the javascript code within the header and that didn't work either. Anyone have any suggestions!? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've included both the auth.js and search.js code, correct?

Comment: yes I did, thanks for checking. I actually tried both sourcing them in as the example suggests, and also tried putting the source directly into the html file. Neither way worked. I also tried placing the javascript code into the header as others suggested in other threads. Have you tried using that code? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've been trying different combinations of this api for days, and I still can't seem to get anything working. Anyone else have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken that code and loaded it onto my server to test, and it worked just fine. Here are a few things to try to eliminate all possible variables:

Use the exact code that I did. I've zipped it up and you can get it here:

http://goo.gl/sSglZB

The ONLY change you'll have to make is to open up the auth.js file and paste your client-ID into the variable declaration near the top of the file. Make sure your client-id has the origin set, in the google cloud console, for the host you'll be running the files on, and this shouldn't be an IP address but an actual hostname (you could also use *).

When running the code, try in Chrome first, then Firefox -- I've seen cases where Firefox fails to load various Google APIs (drive APIs, chart APIs, etc)

If it doesn't work with this code, start looking for places where your setup may be different than what is in this ZIP file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and for posting your code! I really appreciate the help. That said, I'm a little confused about the client-ID. I generated one using Application type: Web application. It doesn't let me use *. I've tried using https://localhost and that didn't work either.

Comment: I just tried on my host as well with your code (and changed the client id). Used http://www.myhostname.com/index.html. When I generated a client id, I used http://www.myhostname.com . No luck  :(

Comment: tried both chrome and firefox as well. On firefox it almost looks like the search button is enabled but you can't click on it. On chrome, it's just disabled.

Comment: Yes ... it's a client for web applications. IT should end in googleusercontent.com I believe. Have you enabled the YouTube Data API in the app as well? It's also in the cloud console, but instead of under the 'credentials' section, it's under the 'APIs' section. Another thing to check is to have the chrome dev tools open when you visit the page, to see if you get any errors.

Comment: yup, my client ID ends in: apps.googleusercontent.com and I do have YouTube Data API v3 enabled in the cloud console. The strange thing is I enable the Youtube Data API and then if I click on the link for it, it just seems like it loads forever. I'm not sure if that's a problem, but that's the only thing I could see that was a potential issue in it. I also tried loading the developer tools and I don't see any errors. All I see on the screen is a text box, and a disabled search button.

Comment: If you go to the API explorer to do a YT API search there, is it functional? https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list

Comment: Ah interesting. **My request was:**

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=asdf&channelType=any&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_Uipe4dMW5FhOgxbWW9cfZR4hAvC8qjCt_MyY33XcHukV4tD4ZsfyC7zO7I6FNFYA
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

**Response:**

400 Bad Request

Comment: what should the redirect URI be?

Comment: There's gotta be something I'm missing in the cloud console! It's been like 2 weeks and nothing i'm trying seems to work, even with your exact code. So either I'm missing something in the cloud console or I don't understand how this works at all. If I'm getting a 400 bad request error, then it must be something else right?

Comment: nevermind, I finally figured out how to use that tool, I now got OK 200. But the code still doesn't work.

Comment: So if the button is never enabled, then the library isn't loading on your page for some reason. The questions I was asking about the api explorer were really to see if there was something on your end blocking the Google APIs altogether, but that doesn't seem to be the case, so something else has got to be going on. Perhaps you should ping me off-list and we can chat in better detail about your setup?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but how do I do that?  :-p  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Here's my work profile: http://odh.byu.edu/directory/jlm59/ it will have my contact info.